# Groovy - working with big numbers

Tags: optimization, groovy, biginteger

I just started to learn Groovy and I'm trying to run a for loop with a limit of a very large number(600851475143 to be exact). Every loop I print the current number.

The problem is after I execute the code, the GroovyConsole and some programs that run in my computer get stuck. I know it's because a lot of ram is being used during the execution of the Groovy script.

Here is the groovy script:

```
BigInteger num = 600851475143
def max = 0
for(BigInteger i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    println i;
}

println "Largest Prime: $max"
```

My question is is there any way to optimize this code so that it won't get stuck or crash?

Comment: obviously the console gets overflown. so if you remove the `println` from the loop, it should consume less memory

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running in the Groovy Console, try running from a command-line:

```
$ groovy -e '
BigInteger num = 600851475143
def max = 0
for(BigInteger i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    println i;
}

println "Largest Prime: $max"'
```

Now, however, you have another problem. Suppose you are able to print out ten thousand numbers per second (a reasonable approximation of my results on my Mac) then, in order to print out six hundred billion numbers you will require sixty million seconds... which is almost two years.

Maybe you should try a somewhat smaller number first.